# How to switch the radio station with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming and trying to make this work.  I want to offer the user the option of selection the radio station they want to listen to...this is what i have come up with, but dont work, any help is appreciated:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // You can place JavaScript like this
    document.getElementById("radiostations").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("radiostations").onchange = resetStation;
    function resetStation(){
            objPlayer = document.getElementById("mediaPlayer");
            // obj.Settings.volume = 75
            newStation = document.getElementById("radiostations");
            objPlayer.URL=newStation.options[newStation.selectedIndex].value;          // playback this file
            objPlayer.controls.play();                                                  // play what ever file is loaded

    }

</script>

<form name="mediaPlay">
    <select name="radiostations" size="1">
        <option selected  value="http://listen.radionomy.com/smoothmusicradio">Smooth Music</option>
        <option value="http://www.urbanhotradio.com/hiphop/music/stream.asx">Hip-Hop</option>
        <option value="http://www.orsradio.com/asx/rnbclassic.asx">R&B Soul</option>
    </select>
    <noscript>
        <input type="button" value="Play Now!"
        onClick="location=document.mediaPlay.radiostations.options
        [document.mediaPlay.radiostations.selectedIndex].value">
    </noscript>
</form>


<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
    STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
    <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE=newStation.options[newStation.selectedIndex].value>
    <PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
    <PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
    <EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC=newStation.options[newStation.selectedIndex].value NAME="MediaPlayer"
        WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="1" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> 
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>​
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these are the only issues, but there are two obvious problems with your JS:

1. You are using `document.getElementById("radiostations")` to reference your select element but the element doesn't have an `id` attribute - you need to add `id="radiostations"` to the markup:

   `<select id="radiostations" name="radiostations" size="1">`
2. Your script block is before the form so the select hasn't yet been parsed by the browser when the JS runs - so it won't be able to access the select element (even after you fix the id problem). You can fix this by either moving the script block to the bottom of the body (or at least somewhere after the select element) and/or by putting the code in an `onload` handler.

(Also I notice inside your `<noscript>` block you have a button that tries to use JavaScript - that's not going to work...)